# Zeros of complex function sequence (Application of Rouche's Theorem).

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, several-complex-variables

For a given sequence of complex functions: $\phi_n(z)= 1+\frac1n-z-e^{-z}$; here $z\in${$z| Rez>0$}.

I want to prove that :

(1).
$\phi_n $ has a unique zero $z_n$ in the half plane. (i.e. there exists a unique $z_n$ in half plane {$z| Rez>0$} s.t $\phi_n(z_n)=0)$.

***[Some how by Rouche's theorem, I almost proved that the function $1+\frac1n-z-e^{-z}$
    has only one zero in half plane {$z| Rez>0$}. But I don't know how to show that $z_n$ is unique s.t. $f_n(z_n)=0$ ]***

(2).
 And further more, I have to show that $z_n\in \Bbb R$.

(3).
 Does $lim_{x\to \infty} z_n$ exist? And If limit exists then what is it?

(I don't have any idea about last two parts.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you start by showing that each $\phi_n$ has a positive real zero. That is an easy consequence of the intermediate value theorem, since all $\phi_n$ are real-valued on $\mathbb{R}$. That way, you are not distracted by thinking about the uniqueness.

Then show that each $\phi_n$ has only one zero in the right half plane. Rouché's theorem is a good option for that, one just has to find the right bounded subregion for it to be applicable. For that, note that no $\phi_n$ can have a zero $z_0$ with $\operatorname{Re} z_0 \geqslant 3$ (arbitrarily chosen value, others work too, just not too small) or $\operatorname{Im} z_0 \geqslant 3$ by the triangle inequality.

For the application of Rouché's theorem, let us choose the rectangle $R$ with vertices $-i\pi,\, \pi - i\pi,\, \pi +i\pi,\, i\pi$. All zeros of $\phi_n$ in the right half plane must lie in the interior of $R$, because

$$\lvert \phi_n(z)\rvert = \left\lvert 1 + \frac1n - z - e^{-z}\right\rvert \geqslant \lvert z\rvert - 1 - \frac1n - \lvert e^{-z}\rvert \geqslant \lvert z\rvert - 3 \geqslant \pi-3 > 0$$

for $\lvert z\rvert \geqslant \pi$ and $\operatorname{Re} z \geqslant 0$.

We apply Rouché's theorem to $f_n(z) = \frac1n - z$ and $g(z) = 1 - e^{-z}$. On the three sides of $\partial R$ that lie in the right half plane, we have

$$\lvert g(z)\rvert \leqslant 1 + \lvert e^{-z}\rvert \leqslant 2 < \pi - 1 \leqslant \lvert z\rvert - \frac1n \leqslant \lvert f_n(z)\rvert.$$

On the side of the rectangle that lies on the imaginary axis, we compute in a different way, we have

$$\left\lvert 1 - e^{-it}\right\rvert^2 = \left\lvert (1-\cos t) + i\sin t \right\rvert^2 = (1-\cos t)^2 + \sin^2 t = 2(1-\cos t) = 4 \sin^2 (t/2),$$

and

$$\left\lvert\frac1n - it \right\rvert^2 = \frac{1}{n^2} + t^2 > t^2 = 4(t/2)^2 \geqslant 4\sin^2(t/2).$$

So we have established that $\lvert g(z)\rvert < \lvert f_n(z)\rvert$ on $\partial R$, and can apply Rouché's theorem to the functions $f_n$ and $\phi_n = f_n+g$ on the rectangle, and conclude that both have the same number of zeros inside $R$. Evidently, $f_n$ has the single zero $\frac1n$ in $\mathbb{C}$, which lies inside $R$, so $\phi_n$ also has a unique zero in $R$.

Finally, for the third point, knowing that the zeros $z_n$ are real allows to approximately locate them with ease, finding $a_n,b_n > 0$ such that $a_n < z_n < b_n$ and such that $\lim (b_n-a_n) = 0$. Then you can see whether $\lim a_n$ exists. $\lim z_n$ exists if and only if $\lim a_n$ exists, and then the two are equal.

Comment: Thank you so much dear Daniel. I just figured out that the way i solved part 1 is also not right. I took the half unit disk at origin as the domain which is not possible because z cannot lie on imaginary axis. Will you please solve part 1 for me. I need to select a proper contour then need to the split the given function into two different functions  in order to apply rouche's theorem. Thanks again.

Comment: I got your point. Do you mean that our domain will be ReZ>equal 3?

Comment: I have added a full proof of that part. You can choose many different domains for the application of Rouché's theorem. If you choose a too small domain (not too small for Rouché's theorem to be applied), showing that all zeros of $\phi_n$ in the right half-plane must lie in that domain can become more difficult, so choosing a larger one makes life easier. The important decision is how to split $\phi_n$ for the application of Rouché's theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. Let me understand this proof.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Your proof is really beautiful and rigorously written. I made a typo in 3rd part. I have edited it now. I think you got this typo because earlier one didn't make any sense. But unfortunately I couldn't understand 3rd part. Please elaborate it. Do we need Hurwitz theorem for it? 
Thanks.

Comment: For small $0 < r$, use the power series of $e^{-r}$. You have $$\phi_n(r) = \frac1n + 1 - r - e^{-r} = \frac1n +1-r-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}r^k = \frac1n - \frac{r^2}{2} + \frac{r^3}{6} -+\dotsb,$$ for $0<r<3$, what remains of the power series is an alternating sum whose terms are decreasing in magnitude, so you can bound $\phi_n(r)$ from below and from above by taking an initial part of the series ending with a negative or positive sign; you can use that to get $a_n < b_n$ with $\phi_n(a_n) > 0 > \phi_n(b_n)$. It is then easy to see how $a_n$ behaves, and also $z_n$.

Comment: In 2nd last paragraph you wrote: 

**Evidently, $f_n$ has the single zero 1n in $\Bbb C$, which lies inside R, so $ϕ_n$ also has a unique zero in R.**

Its all true; but we also need to show that it is a real root of $ϕ_n$ in R. Rouche's theorem doesn't tell us about the place of the zeros. How we handle it? Unless we find the position of $z_n$ we cannot talk about convergence. Is it right? Please correct me If i am wrong. 

Can I put it this way: $ϕ_n$ has only one root; it must be a real one since complex roots always exist in pairs.

Comment: let me read your comment. I didn't notice your comment before writing mine.

Comment: Yes, since $\phi_n$ is real-valued on $\mathbb{R}$, we have $\phi_n(\overline{z}) = \overline{\phi_n(z)}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, so if $\phi_n$ had a non-real root in the right half plane, it would have at least two (conjugate) zeros in the right half-plane. Another way to see that $\phi_n$ has a real zero is the intermediate value theorem. $\phi_n(0) = \frac1n > 0$, and $\phi_n(2) = 1+\frac1n-e^{-2}-2 < 1+\frac1n-2 \leqslant 0$, so $\phi_n$ has a zero in the real interval $(0,2)$.

Comment: Intermediate value theorem really did a cool job. It is all clear now.

Comment: But, I have one more question: In your 2nd last comment, do you want to convey that $lim_{n\to \infty}z_n \to 0$? 
I also couldn't understand last two lines of your comment.

 ***You can use that to get $a_n<b_n$ with $ϕ_n(a_n)>0>ϕ_n(b_n)$. It is then easy to see how $a_n$ behaves, and also $z_n$***
Please explain me little more.

I was just wondering about the application of Hurwitz theorem in last part. Can we apply it to say the same thing more easily.
I truly appreciate your efforts to make me understand this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not using Hurwitz' theorem, I'm thinking of elementary estimates. For real $r > 0$, you have $$\frac{1}{n} - \frac{r^2}{2} < \phi_n(r) < \frac{1}{n} - \frac{r^2}{2} + \frac{r^3}{6}.$$ That gives you $\phi_n\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{n}}\right) > 0 > \phi_n\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$, so the zero lies between $\sqrt{\frac2n}$ and $\frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}$ (for $n > 1$). Hurwitz' theorem works too, but one needs to verify that the $\phi_n$ don't have zeros close to $0$ in the left half-plane to conclude that $z_n \to 0$.

Comment: Now, I understand your approach. And, I want to inquire in it little more. Here $z_n\to 0$ but $0$ is not in right half plane. In the problem $\phi_n$ is defined on the domain - right half plane. So, the sequence of its zeros $z_n$ don't exist in the given domain (but do exist outside it). Am I right Sir?

Comment: The sequence of zeros converges to a boundary point of the domain. The limit function itself has no zero in the domain (if it had, by Hurwitz' theorem, $\phi_n$ would have for large enough $n$ a zero near that, so altogether at least two zeros in the right half plane), but, as it is an entire function, it has a zero at the limit of the $z_n$.

Comment: Now, I understand it inside out. Thank you so much dear Daniel. Have a good day.